# Correct Alignment of Numbers in PASCAL TRIANGLE

Tags: c, pascals-triangle

I made a program for making a pascal triangle and for the input of numbers ( rows ) > 5 , there is an alignment problem i.e for ncr > 10.  Help me out please.
I have included the images for output of the program.

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lefTJ.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int factorial(int number)
{   
    int fact=1;
    for(int i=1; i<=number; ++i )
    {
        fact*=i;
    }
    return fact;
}

int ncr(int n, int r)
{
    int ncr;
    int fact1=factorial(n);
    int fact2=factorial(n-r);
    int fact3=factorial(r);
    ncr = fact1 /(fact2 * fact3);
    return ncr; 
}


int main()
{
    int rows;
    printf("enter the number of rows :\n");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    for(int n=0; n<rows; n++)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=rows-n; i++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(int r=0; r<=n; r++)
        {
            printf("%d ",ncr(n,r));
        }   
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Experiment with spaces and the [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format modifiers (like field width and alignment).

Comment: Hint: store values into a matrix and so you can pre-calculate the with of lines and align your printout.

Comment: Your `ncr` function can easily overflow with input values > 10.

Comment: i am a total noob so i'm still learning c, will look how to create a matrix in c tho.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the inner loop like this

```
for(int i=1; i<=rows-n; i++)
{
   printf("  ");    // Note the extra space
}
for(int r=0; r<=n; r++)
{
   printf("%3d ",ncr(n,r)); // Changed to %3d
}
```

This will work upto 9 rows. If you want it to work for more rows, you can add another space in the first printf and change the second printf to `%5d`

Answer (score 1):

`printf` can take a precision before the formatter. Change `printf("%d ",ncr(n,r));` to `printf("%3d ",ncr(n,r));` to make the numbers 3 characters wide. Also change `printf(" ");` to `printf("  ");`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
printf ("Width trick: %*d \n", 5, 10);
```

this will add 5 more spaces before the digit value.